# How to remove the primitive.E composite literal uses unkeyed fields error?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mongo-go, composite-literals

In this code, I am trying to add a new field in the MongoDB database. But it is giving me a problem in the `update` variable and that is `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive.E composite literal uses unkeyed fields`.  I don't know what to do.

The error is on this part of the code.

```
{"$set", bson.D{
     primitive.E{Key: fieldName, Value: insert},
}},
```

**Code**

```
func Adddata(fieldName, insert string) {
    // Set client options
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")

    // Connect to MongoDB
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    collection := client.Database("PMS").Collection("dataStored")

    filter := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "password", Value: Result1.Password}}

    update := bson.D{
        {"$set", bson.D{
            primitive.E{Key: fieldName, Value: insert},
        }},
    }

    _, err = collection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you see is a lint warning, but not a compiler error. [`bson.D`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) is a slice of [`primitive.E`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.5.2/bson/primitive#E), and you use an unkeyed literal when listing the `primitive.E` values of the slice:

```
update := bson.D{
    {"$set", bson.D{
        primitive.E{Key: fieldName, Value: insert},
    }},
}
```

To get rid of the warning, provide the keys in the struct literal:

```
update := bson.D{
    {Key: "$set", Value: bson.D{
        primitive.E{Key: fieldName, Value: insert},
    }},
}
```

Note that alternatively you may use a [`bson.M`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#M) value to provide the update document, it's simpler and more readable:

```
update := bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        fieldName: insert,
    },
}
```