# How can i use $set and $inc in a single update call in mongodb golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mongo-go

I tried doing this but it didn't work.

```
update := bson.D{{ "$set": bson.D{ "id": "Q" + addr_to_string }, {"$inc": bson.D{ "amount": amount_int } }}}
```

Error:

```
mixture of field:value and value elements in struct literal
```

This is my initial code:

```
update := bson.D{{"$set", bson.D{{"id", "Q" + addr_to_string}, {"amount", amount_int}}}}
```

I try to make amount increment, $inc. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bson.D`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) is to describe a document, an ordered list of properties, where a property is a key-value pair. Properties are described by [`bson.E`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) which is a simple Go struct holding a `Key` and `Value` fields.

So `bson.D` is a slice of structs, so a `bson.D` literal must list struct elements also enclosed in `{}`.

Your input may be written as this:

```
update := bson.D{
    {
        Key: "$set",
        Value: bson.D{
            {Key: "id", Value: "Q" + addr_to_string},
        },
    },
    {
        Key: "$inc",
        Value: bson.D{
            {Key: "amount", Value: amount_int},
        },
    },
}
```

Note that if order doesn't matter (it doesn't matter in this case), it's much more readable and simpler to use [`bson.M`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#M) (which is a map) to define your update document:

```
update := bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        "id": "Q" + addr_to_string,
    },
    "$inc": bson.M{
        "amount": amount_int,
    },
}
```

See related: [How to remove the primitive.E composite literal uses unkeyed fields error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648046/how-to-remove-the-primitive-e-composite-literal-uses-unkeyed-fields-error/67651664#67651664)

Comment: I had one more question. Is it also possible to substract using updateone? I couldn't find that operator.

Comment: @l33t Use `$inc`, but provide a negative number. Adding a negative number is subtracting.